# What's the difference between putOrderedLong vs putLongVolatile vs putLong Java Unsafe?

Tags: java, unsafe

What's the difference between putOrderedLong vs putLongVolatile vs putLong Java Unsafe?I find putOrderedLong and putLongVolatile source code are same

```
void
sun::misc::Unsafe::putOrderedLong (jobject obj, jlong offset, jlong 
value)
{
    volatile jlong *addr = (jlong *) ((char *) obj + offset);
    spinlock lock;
    *addr = value;
}
```